# Code first - Configure Navigation Not Working - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation, ef-code-first, code-first

I´m having a big problem to configure the navigation on my application.

These are the bases (but already with problems)

```
public class ModeloBase
{
    [Key()]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int InseridoPorId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DataInserido { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DataAtualizado { get; set; }

    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    #region Navigation

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("InseridoPorId")]
    public virtual Colaborador InseridoPor { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

    public class Colaborador : ModeloBase
{
    public Colaborador()
    {
        ColaboradoresSubordinadosPorMim = new HashSet<Colaborador>();
    }
    public int SuperiorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SuperiorId")]
    public Colaborador Superior { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Colaborador> ColaboradoresSubordinadosPorMim { get; set; }
}

public class Contato : ModeloBase
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Basically I have a base class "ModeloBase" that all extends it and I want that all thables have a FK to Colaborador with the Column Name "InseridoPorId"

As soon as I try to generate the controller it keep warning me with Multiplicity problems for these Navigation.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: try to change `ModeloBase` to abstract